# Question about LP Model

Tags: linear-programming

I have a aggregate production planning problem. As the company want to have a stable output, the quantities produced per month should (x) not fluctuate to heavily from a specified amount, say g.

So now I want to add a cost factor to my cost function that linearly penalizes every time x deviates from g.

To do this I want basically to do the following: sum( cost * abs(x-g) for every x )

Since I want to model this as a LP programming problem, I need to linearlize this.

Is this possible? If so, could someone explain it to me?

Thanks!